# GitHub "Bad Gateway" when sorting organization repositories by full_name

Tags: github, github-api

Last week I wrote a piece of code which integrates with the GitHub API and fetches a listing of all repositories in a given organization. This does make full use of pagination, fetching 30 items per page. One of the options I added was choosing how to sort the results, which based on [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories), adds this to the query string:

```
sort=[created,updated,pushed,full_name]
```

Based on our requirements, I defaulted this option to sort by Name (`full_name`). Last week, it was working. Today, the same gives me an error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

Along with a JSON body:

```
{
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```

If I sort by any other field, or omit this query parameter altogether, the request works fine. I can even put any garbage non-existent field such as `abc` and I still get a response (without sorting). Also, if I fetch all repositories of a user (instead of an organization), I'm able to sort by `full_name` just fine. I'm just unable to sort by `full_name` when listing organization repositories.

A complete sample request (using `apple` as a sample organization):

```
GET https://api.github.com/orgs/apple/repos?sort=full_name
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there an issue with the API?

---

## UPDATE 1

As of approximately 1.5 hours after posting this question initially, now rather than getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error with a JSON body, now I'm getting `500 Internal Server Error` with no JSON body.

Aaaaand a few minutes after this edit, it's back to the 502 error.

---

## UPDATE 2

To add to the oddity, the failing request using `full_name` takes about 9619ms to respond, whereas the same request sorting by `pushed` takes about 906ms to respond.

Comment: I tried `full-name` and `name` but their results look like wrong (unsorted).

Comment: @EmreSülün I tried too, and while there's no error, it also doesn't sort as needed. Goes along with how I can add any garbage field such as `abc`.

Comment: I suspect your request is timing out and getting killed because it's too expensive. You may try enabling pagination and seeing if that helps, and failing that, contact GitHub support.

Comment: @bk2204 I have no choice but to use pagination. I'm working with over 300 repos, and GitHub forcibly caps that at 100. Either way, I do 30 at a time.

Comment: Then you should definitely contact GitHub support and they'll pass along the message to the developers.